# Arduino Pro micro Serial communication problem with Node MCU

Tags: serial, nodemcu, arduino-micro, arduino-pro-micro, atmega32u4

I recently bought an ATmega32U4 based Arduino Pro micro. I am using the **Keyboard library** and interfacing with my PC via USB.

I am trying to create a serial communication between the Arduino Pro micro and a NodeMCU via Rx, Tx pins (0, 1), but it isn't working i.e. not giving any output with the code below on the Pro micro:

```cpp
#include <Keyboard.h>

int incomingByte;
unsigned long lastTime;
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Keyboard.begin();
}
    
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    lastTime = millis();
    String payload = "";
    
    while (1) {
      if (millis() - lastTime > 1000)
        break;
    
      incomingByte = Serial.read();
      Serial.println(incomingByte);
    }
  }
```

On the NodeMCU there is a simple script flashed which only writes on serial some characters in a delayed loop.

When using the **SoftwareSerial library** with the Pro micro, it is working fine i.e. I can read data sent by the NodeMCU on custom Rx, Tx pins (9, 10). I tried this because I thought since Pro micro is communicating with a PC, the original Rx and Tx pins are busy. But after some research I got to know that unlike other Arduino boards like the UNO, the Pro micro doesn't use those for communication over USB.

Although custom serial using **SoftwareSerial library** is working, it is too slow and unreliable i.e. it takes 2-3 seconds to pass a string of length 10. Also its unreliable because on sending bigger length strings, the strings arrive incomplete or sometimes the data gets corrupted (characters shuffle).

Again this is not my main concern, if I can use original Rx, Tx pins as usual on any other Arduino boards, it solves my issue.

This is my circuit diagram:

[image: Circuit]

Comment: The problem is your janky serial reading method. You're assuming there's data to read when there isn't. Read this: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: I probably missed something but: why are you using SoftwareSerial on the pro micro at all?

Comment: @timemage Yes, you missed that. He explained why - he assumed pins 0/1 were taken with the USB, then found out otherwise, and now is attempting to use those with Serial instead of SoftwareSerial.

Comment: The `Serial` device is usually the USB serial connection, whether or not that is controlled by pins 0/1. For pins 0/1 with a native USB connection you need to use `Serial1`. I think. It's been a while since I used an Arduino with native USB...

Comment: I'm not confused about how Serial and Serial1 work on the 32u4 based Arduinos.  I don't see any indication that anything other than SoftwareSerial is being used.

Comment: @Majenko thanks, replacing `Serial` with `Serial1` worked out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RX and TX pin of Arduino Micro are Serial1. Replace `Serial` in your sketch with `Serial1` to communicate with esp8266 over RX and TX pin.

Comment: Luckily I found out that last night and that worked too. Thanks for your inputs @Juraj.

The Rx and Tx (0 and 1) pins on Arduino Pro Micro are defined with Serial1 so replacing `Serial` with `Serial1` worked out for me. Thanks to all for your interest.